# How to organize several sites with the same base solution with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I have a C#.Net solution for an MVC3 project that will be used for several websites.  The only difference between the sites is some identifier data in the Web.config, and two images.

I don't want to make an entire copy of the base solution projects each time I create a new site.

What are some preferred ways of dealing with such a scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep *developing a single* web site and *deploy it several* times I would recommend to have only one solution for the project. To update *web.config* and images you can write a build script(s) in MSBuild or whatever you would prefer. The script will do:

- XML-poking to update values of web.config
- Update images

This worked for me in similar and more complex scenarios.